# How to Retry 429 Errors On Scroll

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using the elasticsearch dsl library for python. I am running scroll scans in a threaded application like so:

```
s = Search\
    .from_dict(query)\
    .using(es)\
    .index(index)\
    .doc_type(doc_type)\
    .extra(slice=slice)

for hit in s.scan():
    yield hit
```

There can be 32 threads all running on the same scroll with a difference slice. Occasionally this will hit a `429 Too Many Requests` error from this and it kills the whole process. Heart-breakingly, this may occur 1 hour into the scroll and the process just needs to start over.

How can I recover rom a 429 Too Many Requests error? Is it possible to retry at the last scroll offset without restarting the entire scroll?

Answer (score 1):

use the `retry` lib. I have a custom TooManyRequestsError to only catch 429s

```
@retry(TooManyRequestsError, delay=3, jitter=3, max_delay=30)
def get(url: str) -> requests.Response:
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code == 429:
        logger.warning(f'Too many requests! {url}')
        raise TooManyRequestsError()
    res.raise_for_status()
    return res
```